# ¿Cómo completo esta funcion para añadir valores intermedios en un conjunto de puntos X e Y?

Tags: php, bucles

Tengo dos Arrays, con el mismo tamaño siempre, uno con edades y el otro con la cantidad de gente con esa edad. Hay edades en las que el número de personas es 0, pero lo que quiero hacer es una estimación entre la cantidad de gente que tienen las edades más próximas a esta que no tiene datos.

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta ahora, pero no funciona:

```
$ages =  [25, 26, 27, 28,   29, 30, 31, 31, 32];
$people= [1,  5,  6,  null, 7,  5,   7, 12, null];

foreach($ages as $key => $value){
   if($people[$key] == null){
      for($i = $key; $i < count($ages); $i++){
          if($people[$i] != null){
            $people[$key] = ($people[$i]-$people[$key-1])/($i-$key)*$i;
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: que es o significa esto: **una estimación entre la cantidad de gente que tienen las edades más próximas a esta que no tiene datos.** la verda no lo entiendo.

Comment: consejo no deberias de sobre escribir datos: `$people[$key] = ...`

Comment: Aclara tu pregunta, no se entiende lo que quieres hacer... haz un `echo` o `log` de cada variable para que veas que valor tienen.

Comment: quiero hacer una especie de "interpolación" entre los datos, por ejemplo, si los array fueran $ages = [22, 23, 24, 25]; $people = [15, null, null, 30]; que los valores de en medio null convertirlos en 20 y 25.

Comment: 20 y 25 serán elementos del arreglo `$ages`? quieres reemplazar la posición del `null` por la posición que se encuentra el otro arreglo?

Comment: Eso es, para "suavizar" los valores a la hora de ponerlos en una gráfica